# How to check if SqlDataSource.SelectCommand returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

```
I'm using : SqlDatasource1.SelectCommand = "Select Name from Table Where RowID=@RowID";
```

how can I check if the the selectedcommand returned null ( no value found )

Thanks

Comment: Can you please be clear about what you want.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: What kind of null? Many rows with nulls, 0 rows? etc.

Comment: You need to specify the object being returned when using the select command.  A dataset, datatable, datareader, etc.  The answer changes based on how you are getting your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sqlAdapter.Fill(ds);

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
     pnlQueryResults.Visible = true;
}
else
{
     pnlQueryResults.Visible = false;
}

gridView.DataSource = ds;
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlQueryResults" runat="server" Visible="false">
     <div>
         <p>Your query returned no results.</p>
     </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, we could do with a few more details!  But perhaps you've encountered the confusing [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) value that is returned in ADO.NET where we (programmers) tend to expect plain old `null`.

If this is the case, you just need to use something like:

```
if(result is DBNull)
{
    // Null returned
}
else
{
    // Not null.
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting any error just the gridview is empty if there are no values found ..and I need to tell the user : NO value was found